# JavaScript NodeJS HTTP request - variable not accessible in request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am trying to make request on dynamic URL-s from array and I have problem with accessing other global variables in request function. Here is example of my "not working" code

```
var body = '[{"id":"1","node_name":"kihinja","node_key":"2a55f8ecbdfa44f69ed5dee5842b21a5","server_url":"http:\/\/...","long_name":"Kuhinjski senzor","published":"1","check_string":"V6"},{"id":"2","node_name":"rasvjeta","node_key":"0f78f89eee9c481196db3f75691e7237","server_url":"http:\/\/...","long_name":"Stanje rasvjete","published":"1","check_string":"V1"}]';

var JSONObject = JSON.parse(body);
for (var key in JSONObject) {
if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

    console.log(key); //outputs 0,1
    // prepare fetch urls according to their details
    var ftchNodeDetails = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://127.0.0.1:9443/' + JSONObject[key]["node_key"] + '/pin/' + JSONObject[key]["check_string"],
        method: JSONObject[key]["node_key"]
    };

    // run fetch for each node
    request(ftchNodeDetails, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(JSONObject[key]["node_name"]);
        console.log(ftchNodeDetails.method); //prints same result for each key in loop
        console.log(key); //outputs 1,1

    }); // end request

   }
}
```

The thing is that `key`value can not be printed inside `request` part. It can but it prints only max value of array. Why does it print out same values in request? Is there other more elegant way for this? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: change the `var` to `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the way closures work, by the time the fetch returns, your for loop has reached the last element. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue).

You can bind the specific value needed in each iteration. Something like this:

```
var ftchNodeDetails = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://127.0.0.1:9443/' + JSONObject[key]["node_key"] + '/pin/' + JSONObject[key]["check_string"],
method: JSONObject[key]["node_key"]
};

function wrapper(ftchNodeDetails) { 
  request(ftchNodeDetails, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(JSONObject[key]["node_name"]);
    console.log(ftchNodeDetails.method);
    console.log(key); //outputs 1,1
  });
}(ftchNodeDetails);
```

Or, like JLRishe said, use `let`:

```
for (let key in JSONObject) {...}
```

Comment: I have tried `request(ftchNodeDetails, myVariable, function (error, response, body) ` with passing myVariable but againt, it prints the same value. I am not that good, I have tried several things but non of them did not work :(

Comment: Thanks! `for (let key in JSONObject) {...}` worked. I'v just added `let` and it works now. Big thanks!